# Creating multiple kernel threads--not using pthreads

Tags: c, multithreading, linux-kernel, thread-safety, system

I recently started working with `kernel threads` and block IO operation. I have to create multiple threads which should be parallel write operation(LINUX 2.6.32.xx),

What will be the best way to start up?

Comment: If you haven't done so yet, please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Never ask for code , first try something on your own and SO community will help you if you get stuck.

Comment: Sorry, its my mistake i just left empty question, here is code snippet..

key = kmalloc(sizeof(struct key_s), GFP_KERNEL);
     memset(key, 0, sizeof(struct key_s));  
  
      printk("Module starting ... ... ..\n");

      int t, threads=4,ret;
   
  for (t=0; t<=threads; t++){

       task=kthread_run(blk_write(rsrc_hndl,NULL,key,size,value,callback,(void*)key, NULL, "sample thread");

    
      return 0;
               }

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should write some code and then ask something.
But the syscall clone is used for you. So is futex. pthread lib is implemented based on them.
Good luck!

Comment: Sorry, its my mistake i just left empty question, here is code snippet..

static struct task_struct * task;

struct key_s {
//...
}k;
int _init thr_test(void)
key = kmalloc(sizeof(struct key_s), GFP_KERNEL);
     memset(key, 0, sizeof(struct key_s));  
  
      printk("Module starting ... ... ..\n");

      int t, threads=4,ret;
   
  for (t=0; t<=threads; t++){

       task=kthread_run(blk_write(rsrc_hndl,NULL,key,size,value,callback,(void*)key, NULL, "sample thread");

    
      return 0;
               }

@colonel :Whenever i tried to insmod it, i face panic please input me some ideas.